# New SQL Server Installation - Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-2017

I have a new Windows 10 Home machine and I want to install SQL server. I already have Visual Studio 2017 installed and SSMS 2017 (Which I initially though installed SQL).

On first try I got this error:

> VS Shell installation has failed with exit code 1638

And found I needed to Uninstall the Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable (x86) and (x64), install SQL Server, then reinstall the Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable (x86) and (x64). [As seen here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/190090/help-installing-sql-server-2017-vs-shell-installation-has-failed-with-exit-cod)

Then I got this error:

> Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation

[image]

1. I tried the registry key permissions [from this link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83681/setup-error-attempted-to-perform-an-unauthorized-operation)
2. I tried editing my local group policy but Win 10 doesn't have one.
3. I tried exiting from all Firewalls and Anti-malware software.

I have been trying to install SQL Server for 4 weeks now

Edit:

I found the logs but the error seems the same:

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> A security application installed on the server was preventing SQL Server setup to get access

After weeks of Googling i turns out my machine came with a bit of software called [Bull Guard](https://www.bullguard.com/landing-pages/ppc/offer.aspx?&utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=google&utm_content=Offer&utm_campaign=Brand_ROW_English&utm_term=bull%20guard&gclid=CjwKCAiAm7LSBRBBEiwAvL1-L9zsmlGEzwSsQAbt9tJGeuaeeqq-6AFcyU_5F7xd_pnGhj1Pu5Ku4hoCWBAQAvD_BwE) which conflicts with SQL Server. After uninstalling this software the problem was solved. *(Disabling the service didn't work)*

Comment: Disabling didn't work. It isn't the protection it offered that caused the problem it was the fact that the software was installed at all. 

I appreciate the edit though

Comment: if the software doesn't support SQL server to be installed, that is something to notify the manufacturer about.  Disabling security software is not a good long term solution.

Comment: I think that temporarly disabling the service (from windows Services) solves this issue without unistalling the app

Comment: No it didn't. There are messages on their forum about it. The application has to be uninstalled. I wrote to them about it and they are aware of the issue and will be looking at it for the next update.

Comment: @LexEichner ah ok. I think this information is important for other users. and it is better to be included in your answer

Comment: I can confirm this still appears to be an issue with BullGuard. Having attempted a fresh install with SQLServer 2019, which kept failing with a very similar error (`unable to install SQL Server 2019 (setup.exe) exit code (decimal...): attempted to perform unauthorized operation`) despite repeated reinstallation attempts, uninstalling BullGuard, restarting, and re-running a fresh installation worked. How frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

## (1) If the VS issue is not solved

According to the following [MSDN related answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2ffd27d1-cbfe-4233-9baf-9dc00d0d39a4/unable-to-install-sql-server-setupexe-vs-shell-installation-has-failed-with-exit-code-1638?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade)

*"The exit code 1638 means "Another version of this program is already installed", this error message is provided by Windows Installer, please check if you have installed other later version of VS Shell on your machine."*

Also they mentioned that if you have installed Visual studio 2017  this can also affect the installation of SQL Server 2017. The version of VS Shell inside some versions of Visual Studio 2017 is later than the VS Shell inside SQL Server, as a result, you will meet this problem, please check it.*

**The Suggested solution was**

Uninstall Visual Studio 2017, then install SQL Server 2017, after that, install Visual Studio 2017 again.

Also this was the first suggested solution in the link you provided *([Help installing SQL Server 2017 - VS Shell installation has failed with exit code 1638](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/190090/help-installing-sql-server-2017-vs-shell-installation-has-failed-with-exit-cod))*

## (2) If the VS issue is solved

Check for installed applications or running services that are preventing the installation process to get access

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for that. But that isn't the error I was asking about. I just included that to show the history of the error. Continue reading and you will see I resolved that by reinstalling Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable (x86) and (x64). 

I have now solved my issue though

Comment: @LexEichner the solution you provided is very specific and it cannot be predicted by other users. The only solution that i found when searching other than the steps you provided was to uninstall visual studio

Comment: @LexEichner i edited my answer. Now i think any users that are searching for this issue in the future will get all the informations they need from the questiin and answers provided. Good luch

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was related to Microsoft Edge. Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65458145/6751032).

The SQL Express 2014 installation worked after I installed ran the Edge installer (available at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/business/download), opened Edge and checked for updates.